Relationships of code style tools in .net
I am confused of diversity of tools for code style and analyzers. I do not know how to structure these concepts in mind like Roslyn, Roslynator, .editorconfig file, some .net packages like Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, stylecop. How do these tools fit together? What if I want to introduce some existing convention rules into my projects. By the way, I use VS Code for development of .NET projects.
